# extracting regular expressions (regexs) in Stata

Tags: regex, stata

I am using stata, and have a variable called "practice" which has a list of practices and their 5 character code inside parenthesis.

I want to extract the code part only into a new variable. Here is example of what the data in variable "practice" looks like:

```
practice 1 name (JRX76)
practice 2 name but longer (XN6S1)
practice 3 name (4NB87)
practice 4 name but longer (north) (RS236)
practice 5 name (WSZ92)
```

I have used the following code so far:

```
gen code=regexs(2) if regexm(practice, "(\()+([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9])")
```

Which works perfectly, except for on data in the format of the "practice 4" above, for which it extracts "north" rather than "RS236".

I have tried playing around with the $ symbol, but to no success.

I have also not worked out how to combine 'if' statements with regexs, along the lines of the logic
"if you find 2 '(', take the 5 character expression after the second '('".

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction on this please?

Comment: Not the question, but I note that in your example, the desired code is just the last "word" in the string value (in the sense of the function `word()`. (Stripping parentheses is then easy.)

Comment: A follow up to the observation by @NickCox - Based on your example the required substring is always the last word in the string and always 5 characters long. Anybody wishing to avoid using regexs could shorten the solution to `substr(word(practice, -1), 2, 5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess you forgot to take the trailing parenthesis into account when you tried to add the "end-of-string" `$` symbol. To keep it as close as your current regex as possible, I would suggest this one :

```
(\()+([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9])(\))+$
```

Now there are a few improvements I would suggest :

- there's no need to use a "at least one time" `+` quantifier around the parenthesis if they occur precisely one time
- there's no need to add a group around the parenthesis
- if `Stata` supports lookarounds, they could simplify your code
- don't repeat yourself : use quantifiers

So you could try using this one with lookarounds :

```
(?<=\()[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}(?=\)$)
```

Or this one without :

```
\(([a-zA-Z0-9]{5})\)$
```

Comment: Ah, also hadn't put in the '+' before the '$'. This does the job exactly! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to capture parenthesis:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9])(?=\)$)
```

I removed beginning pattern `(\()+` and added `(?=\)$)` to the end which means to look for a literal `)` that's coming at the end of line.